# unbable to connect with winrs when using elastic ip

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, winrm

I am trying to connect to my amazon EC2 server using winrs.
I set an Amazon elastic ip to the server. I am able to connect using the regular ip (ipconfig) but not using the elastic ip.
I also see the listener does not state the elastic ip in the 'ListeninOn' property.

Is there a way to add an ip that the server listens on?

Comment: what do you mean by "connect using the regular ip (ipconfig)"? what is regular IP here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to connect over the instance's public IP? If not, you may have a firewall issue blocking outgoing traffic on port 5985/5986.